# using path of file into command line

Tags: c#, postgresql, cmd

I am developing an application web with asp.net and C# and I would import the shapefile into the database 'postgresql' just by one click, and I tried to search a request in the postgresql that can do this.i use the command line but my problem is in the path in the command how i can send the path of the file. Can you help me please?

```
if (strFileType == ".shp")
{
    txtFilePath.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedShap/" + strFileName + strFileType));

    string strNewPath = Server.MapPath("~/UploadedShap/" + strFileName + strFileType);
    string strCmdText;
    strCmdText = "shp2pgsql -s 3857 '" + strNewPath + "' public.COMGEO | psql -h localhost -d i2s -U postgres -p 5432 -w alami";
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\CMD.exe",strCmdText);
}
```